# OpenShift Console Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, openshift, rhel

Attempting to install Openshift Origin.

Following:
http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_deployment_guide_comprehensive.html#install-the-web-console-rpms

1. Testing the Configuration
   `http://127.0.0.1/console`

**BEGIN ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

NOTE:It appears that the problem has to do with two different versions of rake on my machine as someone was kind enough to suggest I run these commands**

`yum info rubygem-rake`

Name        : rubygem-rake
Version     : 0.8.7
Release     : 2.1.el6
From repo   : rhel-6-server-optional-rpms

`yum info ruby193-rubygem-rake`

Name        : ruby193-rubygem-rake
Version     : 0.9.2.2
Release     : 38.el6
From repo   : openshift-origin-deps

**END ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

**Original Problem**:
When I go to the console directory

`cd /var/www/openshift/console`

`bundle --local`
I receive the message:

`Your bundle is complete!  Use bundle show [gemname] to see where a bundled gem is installed.`

The web site states:

Error message:
**Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
Exception class:
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
Application root:
/var/www/openshift/console**

`#  File    Line    Location
0   /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb  90  in`block in materialize'
1   /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb  83  in `map!'
2   /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb  83  in`materialize'
3   /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb    127 in `specs'
4   /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb    172 in`specs_for'
5   /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb    161 in `requested_specs'
6   /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb   23  in`requested_specs'
7   /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb   11  in `setup'
8   /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb   107 in`setup'
9   /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb    326 in `prepare_app_process'
10  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 156 in`block in initialize_server'
11  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb    563 in `report_app_init_status'
12  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 154 in`initialize_server'
13  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  204 in `start_synchronously'
14  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  180 in`start'
15  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 129 in `start'
16  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    253 in`block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
17  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   132 in `lookup_or_add'
18  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    246 in`block in spawn_rack_application'
19  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   82  in `block in synchronize'
20      prelude>    10:in`synchronize'
21  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   79  in `synchronize'
22  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    244 in`spawn_rack_application'
23  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    137 in `spawn_application'
24  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    275 in`handle_spawn_application'
25  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  357 in `server_main_loop'
26  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  206 in`start_synchronously'
27  /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server 102 in `

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints...  I spent many hours, and attempted many solutions.  Here is what I found.

1. Two versions of ruby were on the machine, and even though `ruby --version` showed the correct 1.9.3 version, it appears that there was a conflicting version 1.8.7 that would run if I attempted bundle install.  So, I removed it.
2. Many duplicate gems, and for some reason, after I removed 1.8.7, if I performed a bundle install, it would begin installing gems that were of too new a version.  So, I was required to  `gem list` followed by `yum list *rubygem*[gemnname]*` to make sure that I only had one version of a gem, and it matched the one from the ruby193 repository.  If I found:

`yum list *rubygem*rdisc*`

ruby193-rubygem-rdiscount.x86_64        1.6.8-2.el6_3     @openshift-origin-deps

gem list rdisc

* LOCAL GEMS *

rdiscount (1.7.2,1.6.8)

I would delete 1.7.2

gem uninstall rdiscount --version 1.7.2

**DON'T FORGET**

1. service openshift-broker restart
2. service openshift-console restart

After each one.